# Kill/stop Istio envoy proxy

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I’m doing some `chaos testing` in `K8s`. My platform use `Istio envoy sidecar`, and as some use case of my chaos scenarios, I would like to stop/kill a envoy proxy without kill the service container, and see what is the standard behavior.

So far I don’t manage to figure how to do it through `kubectl/istioctl`.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Use the /quitquitquit endpoint:

https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/operations/admin#post--quitquitquit

curl -sf -XPOST http://127.0.0.1:15020/quitquitquit

Answer (score 1):

You might try and configure your Istio Virtual Service with a [secondary HTTP route](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPRoute) with a [Route Destination](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#RouteDestination):

- pointed to nowhere,
- with a weight of 0 (so not receiving any traffic)

Setting that weight to 100 would activate that fake route, effectively "killing" the router (in that it sends the traffic to "nowhere"), while the service remains active.

Comment: Inspiration: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/04/10/istio-chaos-engineering#never_gonna_give_you_up, mentioned in https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/36771